# How to set the project `FrameworkType` from the IDE?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe3, delphi-xe4

In your `.dproj` file, you can set the framework like this:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
<!-- -->
        <FrameworkType>VCL</FrameworkType>
<!-- -->
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

`FrameworkType` can be `None`, `VCL`, `FMX`, or `FMI` (the latter is for FreePascal based iOS applications).

How can you set this `FrameworkType` from the IDE without manually editing the `.dproj` file (for instance when porting from one platform to the other)?
(Preferably for Delphi XE2 and up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot modify this setting from the IDE.

Comment: Any sources to documentation about this?

Comment: I'm not sure where in the documentation you can find this, but once a framework is set, it cannot be changed [using IDE]

Comment: It would seem unlikely that the documentation describes things that cannot be done.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan so there is no OTA hook for this?

Comment: There is `IOTAProject160.FrameworkType`, which is a read only property. Surely you could have found this yourself by performing the same search that I just did.

Comment: Which search did you do? I somehow missed it in https://www.google.com/search?q=Delphi+FrameworkType+OTA

Comment: You have to search the source code in the ToolsAPI folder. It's all undocumented and you have to work it out for yourself.

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers You asked the question, and I answered it. What more are you looking for?